# Сортировка двумерного массива по второму столбцу

Tags: массивы, pascalabc.net

Имеется двумерный массив:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо привести его к такому виду:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите пожалуйста.

Пример кода, в котором я уже пытался.

```
const N=10; const M=30;
var 
z:array[1..N, 1..M] of byte;
x:array[1..N] of integer;
y:array[1..11, 1..3] of integer;
rab: array[1..N] of integer;
bar: array[1..N] of integer;
i, j, sum, k1:integer;

begin
 
for i:=1 to N do
 begin
   for j:=1 to M do
    begin
      z[i,j]:=random(2);
    end;   
 end;

writeln('Табель отработанных дней');  
for i:=1 to N do
begin
   write(i,': ');
   for j:=1 to M do
    begin
      write( z[i,j], ' ');
    end;
   writeln();
end;
sum:=0;
for i:=1 to N do
 begin
   for j:=1 to M do
    begin
      sum := sum + z[i, j];
    end;
    writeln(i,'-ый Работник: ', sum);
    x[i]:=sum;
    if(sum>=30) then
    begin
      writeln('Работник ', i,' не пропускал рабочие дни');
    end;
    sum:=0;
 end;
writeln();
for i:=1 to 10 do
begin
  for j:=1 to 2 do
  begin
    y[i][1]:=i;
    y[i][j+1]:=x[i];
 write(y[i,j]:3);
  end;
  writeln();
end;
writeln();

for i:=1 to 10 do
begin
for j:=1 to 2 do
begin
if y[i, j+1]>y[i+1, j+1] then
begin
  k1:=y[i, j+1];
  y[i, j+1]:=y[i+1, j+1];
  y[i+1, j+1]:=k1;
end; 
end;
end;
for i:=1 to 10 do
begin
for j:=1 to 2 do
begin
  write(y[i,j]:3);
end;
writeln();
end;
end.
```

Comment: Да. И еще я в вопросе добавил картинки. Может понятнее будет.

Comment: можете привести код, что вы уже пробовали?

Comment: Пробовал приспособить для этого пузырьковую сортировку.

Answer (score 1):

PascalABC.NET

```
##
var m := Matr(5, 2, 1, 12, 2, 10, 3, 19, 4, 22, 5, 9);
m.Print;
Writeln;
m := MatrByRow(m.Rows.OrderBy(r -> r[1]));
m.Print
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Пишете в среде PascalABC.NET - используйте язык PascalABC.NET, а не Turbo Pascal и будет Вам счастье.
Вот код для последней версии языка.

```
##
var (m, n) := (5, 2);
var a := Matr(m, n, |1, 12, 2, 10, 3, 19, 4, 22, 5, 9|);
a.Println;
Writeln;
var v := a.Col(1).Select((v, i) -> (v, i)).OrderBy(t -> t[0]).ToArray;
var b := new integer[m, n];
for var i := 0 to m - 1 do
   b.SetRow(i, a.Row(v[i][1]));
b.Print
```